# How are the Extremely Large and Thirty Meter Telescopes coming along ("planned 2027")

Tags: telescope, observatory, future

The graphic above is oft-cited in SE questions and answers. I was (a little) sad to see in it that the 100 meter telescope-engineering wunderkind [Overwhelmingly Large Telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overwhelmingly_Large_Telescope) or "OWL" has been canceled, leaving the Extremely Large (37 meter) and Thirty Meter (30 meter) Telescopes coming along ("planned 2027") to become the (seemingly) largest two single-aperture optical telescopes for quite some time into the future.

Are they both coming along nicely and on-track for first light circa 2027, now only 4 years away?

---

Wikimedia's [Comparison optical telescope primary mirrors](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Comparison_optical_telescope_primary_mirrors.svg) (click link above, or image below for full size & resolution)

[image: Wikimedia's "Comparison optical telescope primary mirrors" https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Comparison_optical_telescope_primary_mirrors.svg]

Comment: Literally the first News item on their web pages. https://elt.eso.org/media/

Comment: @ProfRob literally is better than figuratively when it comes to new items for sure!

Answer (score 3):

The ELT looks basically on track. It’s scheduled to start scientific observations in 2028 and is now half-completed. See https://www.eso.org/public/news/eso2310/

The TMT’s fate is less positive, though, as construction stopped in 2018 due to protests from Native Hawai’ians that it was encroaching a sacred mountain—from what I understood, it had basically been agreed with the Native Council that construction would indeed go forward, but some nonmembers of the Council see things in a different way and disagreed with the Council’s decision, and *they* are the ones who cause trouble. Wikipedia’s page says that as of June 2022, “no further construction has been announced or initiated” since the 2018 stop.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty_Meter_Telescope
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposition_to_the_Mauna_Kea_Observatories
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty_Meter_Telescope_protests

Comment: The Globe and Mail, July 23, 2019 [Thirty Meter Telescope dispute puts focus on Canada’s role](https://www.theglobeandmail.com/canada/article-thirty-meter-telescope-dispute-puts-focus-on-canadas-role/)